# I want to write this idea in php

Tags: php

i want a input field where i can write in a number from 0 to 10.
if i write number 10 the output must be 9,7,5,3,1
or if i would write the number 8 the output should be 7 5 3 1 
So only the odd numbers must be outputted when clicked on submit after
putting a number in the input form. html is combined with this php code i think.
please help.

Comment: Have you tried something?

Comment: Did you try anything yet ?

Comment: Show me what you have tryed so i can try assist

Comment: i have nothing tried yet.
there must be a function for a variable. thats what i know

Comment: if you could help me out it would made my day very well today.

Comment: sounds like homework to me. please not that stackoverflow is not a code generator

Comment: You need a custom code for that.. You also need to try something yourself . if you have a idea then try it

Comment: People are unlikely to want to help you much if you haven't made any attempt at doing this yourself

Comment: how am i supposed to do somthing myself when im just a learner.
i learn alot from others or just by seeing the code and looking up for a logical explanation by myself.

Comment: @Josef, I'm writting some simple scripts for you so take heart

Comment: The best way to learn is by doing, not simply by asking others to do it for you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  <form action="#" method ="post">
<input type="text" name="number">
<input type="submit" name ="submit" value="submit">
</form>
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
$number = $_POST['number'];
for($i=$number;$i>0;$i--){
  if($i%2 != 0 ) // modulo prueba por pares o impares
     echo $i.'<br>';
}
}
```

Please check above code

Comment: Thanks, it works but maybe a achange would be good to let the inputted number not output

Comment: can you edit the code so that the ouput begins from high to low order?

Answer (score 0):

try this one

```
$inputNumber = intval($_POST[inputNumber"]);
for($i = $inputNumber ; $i >=1 ; $i--){
  if($i % 2 == 1){
    echo $i." ";
  }
}
```